# Amount of bridge hands in 4-3-3-3 distribution

Tags: combinatorics

> It is said that a bridge hand has a 4-3-3-3 distribution if it has 4 cards in one suit and 3 cards in the other suits. For example, a hand with 3 clubs and 4 hearts, 3 diamonds and 3 spades is a 4-3-3-3 distribution.
>
> How many bridge hands with a 4-3-3-3 distribution are there?

I'd argue it would be 4, one for each suit, but my TA said it'd be a big number. I assume it would involve binomial coefficients as well as the product rule, but I'm not quite sure. Any hints?

Comment: If you said “4” you have really misunderstood a question.  Here are three examples of bridge hands with a 4-3-3-3 distribution: $$\spadesuit AK72\quad \heartsuit 943\quad \diamondsuit Q92\quad \clubsuit J76\\ 
\spadesuit 432\quad \heartsuit 432\quad \diamondsuit 5432\quad \clubsuit 432\\ 
\spadesuit 965\quad \heartsuit AKQJ\quad \diamondsuit AK4\quad \clubsuit 953\\ 
$$

It should be clear that there are thousands upon thousands of others.

Comment: I see, you're right. Am I at least on the right path in my assumption as in what to do?

Comment: It will definitely involve binomial coefficients as well as the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There are four choices for the suit of four cards

Then you have to allocate cards for each suit - choosing three out of thirteen for three of the suits and four out of thirteen for the fourth suit. Check that you can make these choices independently.

Combine this information using the rules you know.

The biggest challenge with these kinds of problems is to break them down into smaller chunks for which the rules are easy, then to combine the easy pieces in an appropriate way. With cards the suits are often useful, but sometimes, in poker hands for example, the face values can be a better way of doing things. I've sketched this out in the hope that you have some other questions you could try out. For example 4432 is the most common pattern for bridge hands. Can you count the number of possibles for that and show that it is greater than the number of 4333 pattern hands?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a similar problem that is simpler.  Poker hands contain five cards.  A 4-1-0-0 hand is one that has four cards of one suit, one card of a second suit, and no cards of the other two suits.  How many such hands are there?

First, we will assign the suits.  Let's say that the suit in which we have 4 cards is the "big suit" and the suit in which we have one card is the "off suit".  There are 4 choices ($\spadesuit\heartsuit\diamondsuit\clubsuit$) for which suit is the big one, and then whatever we pick there are 3 remaining choices for the off suit.  Once we've picked those two we don't care about the two remaining suits.  So there are $\color{darkblue}{12}$ ways to select the suits.

In the off suit, we could have any of $\color{darkgreen}{13}$ cards.

In the big suit, we could have any 4 of the 13 cards.  There are $\color{darkred}{13\choose 4}$ possible choices of 4 cards.

Each of these three choices (which suits we hold, which card we hold in the off suit, and which 4 cards we hold in  the big suit) is independent of the others, so by the product rule, we can find the total number of ways of making all three choices  by multiplying the three together.  The total number of 4-1-0-0 hands is $$\color{darkblue}{12}\cdot \color{darkgreen}{13} \cdot \color{darkred}{\binom{13}4} = 111,\!540.$$